# Can't run a program installed through gem install

Tags: ruby, gem

I have installed Ruby using RVM.

I did a gem install rspec command and it seemed to install rspec correctly. If I do a rspec  I get a "The program 'rspec' is not currently installed" and I am suggested to apt-get it.

If I try to do a gem install rspec again, it shows that rspec was already installed. I tried to do sudo gem install rspec thinking it might be permission problem but then the terminal said that the gem program wasn't installed.

How can I run the programs I have "gem installed" in Ubuntu without resorting to doing an "apt-get"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that the ruby version from my gem environment was different than from the ruby version from rvm.

I used the commands

```
gem env
which ruby
```

To diagnose the problem. This gave me the ruby version used by gem and rvm and then used

```
rvm use <ruby-version>
```

To match the two ruby versions.

I made a blog post with more details: [Problems running the executable from a gem installed under rvm](http://gillesleblanc.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/problems-running-the-executable-from-a-gem-installed-under-rvm/)

Answer (score 1):

When you use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) instead RVM  you have option to run `rbenv rehash`, which will put gem binaries to path so you can use it. Also, you need to run `rbenv rehash` every time you install new gem that provides binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't appear to have rvm at all on Ubuntu 15.04. The solution was to install the `rbenv` package. Now everything I have installed through "gem install" can now be executed.